# NestJS and TypeORM Exception Filter: Get Status is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm developing an app using NestJS and TypeORM. My goal is to catch TypeORM errors and it could be done using [exception filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters).

But my problem is, I'm encountering this error:

`(node:345) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: exception.getStatus is not a function`

This is similar to this github post discussing the [problem](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/538) but it's not working on my end.

Here's my setup:

```
@Catch(QueryFailedError)
export class TypeORMQueryExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        const status = exception.getStatus(); //error here
....
```

I've declared this globally so,

**main.ts**

`app.useGlobalFilters(new TypeORMQueryExceptionFilter())`

**app.module.ts**

```
....
providers: [

        {
            provide: APP_FILTER,
            useClass: TypeORMQueryExceptionFilter
        }
    ]
...
```

If you have an idea resolving why `getStatus()` of HttpException is undefined, it would be a big help.

**Update**

As this line suggests `catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {` in relation to `@Catch(QueryFailedError)`, I could assume that `HttpException` is the wrong type for param exception. It should be,if ever, `catch(exception: QueryFailedError, host: ArgumentsHost) {` instead.

Thus, since the `QueryFailedError` data structure is this:

```
export declare class QueryFailedError extends TypeORMError {
    readonly query: string;
    readonly parameters: any[] | undefined;
    readonly driverError: any;
    constructor(query: string, parameters: any[] | undefined, driverError: any);
}
```

I believe that `const status = exception.getStatus();` is not needed so we could re-write or eliminate `const status = exception.getStatus()` to `const status = exception.driverError()`. This is relation to the example [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters).

Since `QueryFailedError` doesn't represent any http error codes in its properties, one solution could have to hard code the http status response like this:

```
response
            .status(500)
            .json({
                statusCode: 500,
                timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                path: request.url,
            });
```

Can someone validate this as it could be I just did something wrong as `exception: HttpException` should be working anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instances of `QueryFailedError` doesn't has the method `getStatus`. Fix the types of your filter:

```js
@Catch(QueryFailedError)
export class TypeORMQueryExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: QueryFailedError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
```